# Maven not installing dependencies correctly

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a java project with dependencies from a Maven private repo. Upon initial set up maven built the project correctly but now projects from the private repo have to be built manually/ locally( `mvn clean install -U` in the project used to work). When I try to run the project, everything compiles correctly, however upon runtime I get a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`.  These are all from Maven private repos that need to be recompiled locally for the project in question to run.

There are two things that happened around the same time: 1) I had to update my password to the Maven Private repo, however, I updated my credentials stored locally on my computer and when I try `mvn clean install -U` I can see the dependencies downloading correctly. 2) I am new to Java / Intellij and when trying to delete a class file I accidentally deleted the entire module. Not sure if this broke some link somewhere I may just not be aware of?

I've cleared the cache, deleted the entire .m2 dir contents and started from scratch, deleted the entire project directory and restarted again but still get the same issue.

Comment: Have you checked your ~/.m2/settings.xml file after deletion? Usually it contains links to private repositories which contain build artifacts.

Comment: Yeah, I have a designated settings.xml file that is used company wide.. will not have changed.

Comment: You should take a look at the IntelliJ IDEA settings.xml file. You can see it into Files -> Settings -> (type maven in the search box) -> User settings file. Check the file the IDE is pointing.

Comment: Sorry Rhuan, don't understand where you mean

Comment: Have correctly given those things which are missing as dependencies ? If you have a NoClassDefFoundError you obviously have not...or you are starting the wrong file..

Answer (score 0):

It might happen when you have duplicate libraries . Please check the maven dependency tree. You should get an insight. You can use  tag to remove the duplicate jars.

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>sample.ProjectA</groupId>
  <artifactId>Project-A</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
      <groupId>sample.ProjectB</groupId>
      <artifactId>Project-B</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions> 
</dependency>
```